# Removing Wild Tangent metro apps from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, bloatware

I just got a new Windows 8 computer and I uninstalled the 'Wild Tangent' application that came with the computer, however, on the start page, I still see 'All Casual Games', 'All Kids Games', etc and when I click on them I am brought to a WildTangent web page. When I click 'uninstall', I am brought to the add/remove programs in the desktop environment but see nothing having to do with WT (as I have already uninstalled it from there).

Any Ideas how to get this bloatware to go away?

UPDATE: As I have read online, after I uninstall something I could just delete the associated entries in Program Files. I deleted the WildTangent folder in Program Files and now the apps on the metro UI are still there, but when I click on them it just brings me back to the desktop and not even to a webpage. The icons are still there in the 'Games' folder but they no longer have any details about them and when I click them nothing happens - when I right click them nothing happens either. Any ideas on how to get rid of these traces of Wildtangent? I plan on using my computer for gaming and want to have my games organized!

Comment: Usually for metro apps you just right-click the tile on the start screen and choose "uninstall". Does that not work in this situation?

Comment: Nope. When I click 'uninstall', I am brought to the add/remove programs in the desktop environment but see nothing having to do with WT (as I have already uninstalled it from there).

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like these could be links, not actual Metro apps. A metro app should always uninstall from the start screen like that. Look around in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and see if there are any offending links there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very delayed answer.
Look in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX\Games

In that folder, there's an entry for each game icon in the apps screen. Delete them and restart Windows. They're now gone at last.

Answer (score 1):

If you already removed WildTangent Games from Programs and Features (Control Panel).
For the annoying Apps in Windows 8 Metro, go to c:\Program Files (x86)\Wild Tangent\
There are still an uninstall.exe and some files. Double click uninstall.exe and everything will be gone.
(No need for extra registry trick)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that PC Decrapifier (http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/) should be able to do the things that you're looking for. It will check for all the bloatware that came with the machine, and offer to remove it.

Here's an overview from their own site:

> Is your PC running slowly? Even brand new PCs often come with LOTS of
>   pre-installed software that can cause that new machine to come to a
>   crawl. Not to mention all of the annoying pop-ups! Others may have a
>   PC that's a couple years old and we're the ones that installed a bunch
>   of junk! It happens to the best of us. We try a bunch of programs over
>   time and forget to remove them.

[Image of PCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihDTg.png)

Comment: @karel (and amckern) The guidelines for recommending software are [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). I think this answer would benefit from some editing based on those guidelines but it doesn't look like spam to me. What spammer would recommend two software products that have no relation to each other, and warn about an undesirable feature of one of them?

Comment: @amckern Why are you even promoting a program like this?  Its complete and total snake oil.  Ridiculous you would even promote a program like this.